# Open Sharepoint folder with windows explorer from CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2011, webdav

I've been struggling with this issue for a while now, 
and hope maybe someone in the community can provide a resolution.

I have a requirement which is to put a button on the a CRM account form which will have the same logic as the Open With Explorer button in a Sharepoint document library. The logic is required as the users have to do several click in order to get to this button, and open the required account's folder in windows explorer, which are:

1. Click Documents in navigation of the form, to open SP integration
2. Click documents in the SP view
3. Click library
4. Click the Open With Explorer button

The CRM is integrated with Sharepoint, and when the folder is opened in windows explorer it has the following sample link

http://{sharepoint}/CRM/7F9F72A1-4591-E011-AC6C-00155D773703/Documents/

Where the GUID 7F9F72A1-4591-E011-AC6C-00155D773703, is the account id in CRM.

From my research i have found that the javascript function that achieves this is 
*NavigateHttpFolder* from the sp.js in Sharepoint.

From this function, and this link [About Web Folder Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531432.aspx)
I've completed the following function.

```
var httpFolderDiv = document.createElement("SPAN");

function NavigateToFolder() {

    document.body.appendChild(httpFolderDiv);
    httpFolderDiv.onreadystatechange = NavigateToFolder;
    httpFolderDiv.id = "navDiv";
    httpFolderDiv.addBehavior("#default#httpFolder");
    if (httpFolderDiv.readyState == "complete") {
        httpFolderDiv.onreadystatechange = null;
        var link = "";
        var account = "";
        var accountid = "";
        var id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().replace("{", "").replace("}", ""); 
        link = "http://{sharepoint}/CRM/" + id + "/Documents/";

        try {
             httpFolderDiv.navigateFrame(link, "_blank"); 
        } catch (c) {
            alert(c.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

This function opens up the folder from Sharepoint in windows explorer, but with limitation if only that folder was previously opened directly from Sharepoint.
I believe that the logic I am missing in the code, is that I don't do mapping of the folder, the way sharepoint does.

I am aware that this folder can be mapped manually as a network drive, [Connecting WebDAV Server Using Web folders](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/windows/windows), but this will not do the trick for me as this will have to be done on every client.

How can I achieve this by grabbing the complete logic from SP, or maybe running a console command from javascript to map the folder prior to opening it with the above function.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, since this has been posted, but I stumbled upon it while searching for the exact same problem.

Here's what worked for me in SharePoint 2013:

```
<a href='#' onClick="javascript:CoreInvoke('NavigateHttpFolder', '[path to site]/[library name]/', '_blank');">
Click to open in Explorer
</a>
```

It's essentially the same function used by SharePoints own functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I am unable to verify this now as i do not have access to those CRM and SP environments. 
But if you could answer following questions would be of help.

1.Can you provide a screenshot of the fix if possible? 
2. Does the even work from Dynamics CRM, or maybe from another external page? 
3. Also which JS files need referencing in order to invoke the function (if its an external page, meaning not withing Sharepoint)?